# How to split a number into its digits in APL

Tags: split, numbers, apl

In APL, how can I split an integer or number into a vector containing its digits? What is the most concise (shortest) way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the inverse of `Decode` with base 10:

```
10⊥⍣¯1⊢
```

since `Decode` would take in as many digits as needed and decode them, its inverse would take a number and encode it to as many digits as needed,

or, with `⎕IO←0`, you can try to find the indexes of the formatted number inside the digits vector:

```
⎕D⍳⍕
```

[Demo for both solutions.](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbBEODR11LH/UuPrTe8FHXIq5HfVM9/YHCBlzpQBLIc3nUu/lR71SgYgVDI2OuNAVTM3NjCyBtaGlhbGRmwpUOFk@HiqfDxAE)

This is better than the uglier use of `Encode` with custom length derived by shaping an array of 10 to the length of the log<sub>10</sub> of the input:

```
{⍵⊤⍨10⍴⍨⌈10⍟1+⍵}
```

Comment: Just to be complete, the "old school" encode method would be something like  `(10⍴10)⊤1234567890`  ==  `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0`

Comment: that works, but what does the `⊢` do (in your first example)? I am new to APL, and as far as I know it returns its right argument (but it doesn't have one here?).

Comment: @ed588 it is there to complete the expression into a train, so you can assign it to a variable as a function (`10 (⊥⍣¯1) ⊢`). the `⊥⍣¯1` is a function on itself, so you need to associate the 10 somehow.

Comment: so does that mean that `f←10⊥⍣¯1⊢` is (roughly) equivalent to `f←{10(⊥⍣¯1)⍵}`?

Comment: @ed588 not just roughly; another common form is `(10∘⊥⍣¯1)` which means (roughly) "compose 10 as constant first argument of this function"

Answer (score 4):

I did this in APL2 by first applying FORMAT and then EXECUTE EACH (though it might be limited to positive integers) :

```
⍎¨⍕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhEe9fYdWPOqdCuQpGBoZc6UpmJqZG1sAaUNLC2MjMxMA)

Comment: As simple (though doubtlessly inefficient) as that is, I never would have thought of it.  Yet another example of how there's always a dozen ways to do the same thing in APL.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most concise, but the power to do this was in the earliest APL.  [The 1962 book](http://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Books/APROGRAMMING%20LANGUAGE) shows how to work with positional number systems using only basic functions and matrix multiply:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do it obviously:
`a⊤⍨10×b÷b←⍳⌈10⍟a←⍵`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).