# How to test for string input? (Dyalog APL)

Tags: validation, error-handling, control-flow, apl, dyalog

I was working on this function `Happy` to practice control flow. `Happy` tests if a number is a happy number. I was trying also to learn error handling. So, I tried to catch if a user input is anything other than an integer. Especially if the input is a string. For this I tried to incorporate the scalar test [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160789/error-handling-in-apl)  But I could not test it on the editor because if I try to enter any letters without quotes I get of course a `VALUE ERROR: Undefined name`.

Also, *Mastering APL* book warns about using Quad for data input.

What is the correct way to test if an input is a string? I assume that the user will enter letters without quotes.

(I'm using Dyalog APL 17.0)

(I took the code about how to split the number into its digits from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44990891/5576938)?)

```
Happy
 'Enter a Number'
 N←⎕
 N2←N
 :If N<0
     N←|N
     'You entered'N2
     'Only positive numbers can be happy'
     'We will check if'N'is happy'
     N2←N
 :EndIf
 f←10⊥⍣¯1⊢
 D←f N
 N←+/D×D
 ⍝:If 0≢⊃0⍴⊂N
 ⍝:OrIf N≢⌊N
 ⍝    'You entered: 'N'Enter an integer'
 ⍝    →0
 ⍝:EndIf
 :If N=1
     '***************'
     'Yes'N2'is happy!'
     '***************'
 :Else
     :While N≠1
         N←+/D×D
         D←f N
         N←+/D×D
         'N is:'N
         :If N=4
             '**********************************'
             'Sorry!'N2'is not a happy number'
             '**********************************'
             :Leave
         :EndIf
         :If N=1
             '**********************'
             'Yes!'N2'is a happy number'
             '**********************'
         :EndIf
     :EndWhile
 :EndIf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

Without further ado, here's a suggested solution:

```
 Happy;ok;N;N2
 'Enter a Number'
 ok←0
 :While ~ok
     N2←N←⍞  ⍝ N2=original input
     ok←∧/N∊⎕D,'¯.'  ⍝ allow high minus for negatives and decimal separator
     (~ok)/'Please enter numeric data!'
 :EndWhile
 N←2⊃⎕VFI N  ⍝ result of ⍞ will be text, so make it numeric
 N←⍬⍴N       ⍝ make it a scalar 
 :If N<0
     N←|N
     'You entered'N2
     'Only positive numbers can be happy'
     'We will check if'N'is happy'
     N2←N
 :EndIf
 f←10⊥⍣¯1⊢
 D←f N
 N←+/D×D

 :If N=1
     '***************'
     'Yes'N2'is happy!'
     '***************'
 :Else
     :While N≠1
         N←+/D×D
         D←f N
         N←+/D×D
         'N is:'N
         :If N=4
             '**********************************'
             'Sorry!'N2'is not a happy number'
             '**********************************'
             :Leave
         :EndIf
         :If N=1
             '**********************'
             'Yes!'N2'is a happy number'
             '**********************'
         :EndIf
     :EndWhile
 :EndIf
```

Remarks

- Legrand is right about not using `⎕`, use `⍞` instead. This gives you the "untranslated" string so that you can work with it. Using the system to evaluate user input (without error-trapping) could open the doors to all sorts of attacks. *(Documentation [here](https://help.dyalog.com/17.0/index_CSH.htm#Language/System%20Functions/Character%20Input%20Output.htm))*
- I used `⎕VFI` (which is a Dyalog-specific system-function, I think) that verifies input. This is preferreable to `⍎` which (again) could open doors...*(Documentation [here]](https://help.dyalog.com/17.0/index_CSH.htm#Language/System%20Functions/vfi.htm))*

Comment: „Digits“. There‘s also {Quad}A for „Alphabet“

Comment: I was confused, so that's not the D I used in the function as `D←fN` where I calculate the digits of N?

Comment: ok,I had replied from my phone...but I see additional things that should be mentioned. Will update my teply later today ;)

Comment: ok, thanks. I tried it. It works but it catches numbers too and the rest of the function is not executed.

Comment: Thanks! I'm studying your answer. Ok, so I thought that Quote Quade took only string input. But I see that the user can enter numeric input but Quote Quade converts it to string: chars←⍞ 123 chars 123 +/chars DOMAIN ERROR.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `⍞` (*Character Input*; [documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/Character%20Input%20Output.htm)) rather than `⎕`. `⍞` will give you the literal text which the user entered.

```
input←⍞
```

You can then use `⎕VFI` (*Verify and Fix Input*; [documentation](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/System%20Functions/vfi.htm)) on the result to check for numeric input. It will give you a vector of two vectors. The first is Boolean and indicated for each "word" in the argument. The second vector is numeric containing one number per word. Invalid words become zero.

```
(valid values)←⎕VFI input
```

So if you are looking for a single number check the validity vector, and then you can check for being an integer:

```
:If valid≢,1
:OrIf values≢⌊values
    'You entered: 'N'Enter an integer'
    →0
:EndIf
```

Finally you can extract `N`:

```
N←⊃values
```

---

#### Some unrelated advice

1. Remember to localise your variables by listing them at the top, each preceded by a `;`.
2. Use `:Else` for the rest of the program instead of `→0` to avoid jumping.
3. Similarly, you can avoid jumping with `:Leave` by changing `:EndWhile` to `:Until N=4`.
4. You code may be easier to read if you state your conditions in the positive.
5. To avoid unwanted spacing, concatenate your output (with `,`) rather than stranding (juxtaposing) it.
6. Precede output with `⎕←` to make it easier to spot and increase clarity.

```
 Happy;input;valid;values;N;N2;f;D
 ⎕←'Enter a Number'
 input←⍞
 (valid values)←⎕VFI input
 :If valid≡,1
 :AndIf values≡⌊values
     N←⊃values
     N2←N
     :If N<0
         N←|N
         ⎕←'You entered',N2
         ⎕←'Only positive numbers can be happy'
         ⎕←'We will check if',N,'is happy'
         N2←N
     :EndIf
     f←10⊥⍣¯1⊢
     D←f N
     N←+/D×D
     :If N=1
         ⎕←'***************'
         ⎕←'Yes',N2,'is happy!'
         ⎕←'***************'
     :Else
         :While N≠1
             N←+/D×D
             D←f N
             N←+/D×D
             ⎕←'N is:',N
             :If N=4
                 ⎕←'**********************************'
                 ⎕←'Sorry!',N2,'is not a happy number'
                 ⎕←'**********************************'
             :EndIf
             :If N=1
                 ⎕←'**********************'
                 ⎕←'Yes!',N2,'is a happy number'
                 ⎕←'**********************'
             :EndIf
         :Until N=4
     :EndIf
 :Else
     ⎕←'You entered: ',input,' Enter an integer'
 :EndIf
```

Comment: That's great! Thanks. Especially for the unrelated advice. I'll read it carefully tomorrow.